# Is it a good idea to use the HTTP Accept-Language header to set the locale of the user?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

i use vuejs with  laravel . i want set user local . i use this way? is it good?

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
    function (config) {
        config.headers['Accept-Language']='en' or 'fr'
          return config;
    },
    function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

in middleware

````
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->header('Accept-Language'))
            \App::setLocale($request->header('Accept-Language'));
        return $next($request);
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Please help me !

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is good to use Accept-Language for content negotiation of a REST API.